# shallow nodes and deeper nodes

Tags: data-structures

I found that in some tutorial the breadth first search

the shallow nodes are expanded before deeper nodes.

I am really confused what is the meaning of each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terms "shallow" and "deep" come from visualizing your graph with the starting node at the top: the "depth" of a node is the number of edges that you need to traverse in order to get to that node from the starting node. The statement about BFS tells you that nodes with fewer edges between them and the starting node are discovered before nodes separated from the start by more edges.

Comment: Ok but let say we have a tree with 3 nodes , the right child and left child have the same depth from the root , (equals number of edges ,right? so why expand the left child first?

Comment: @JasmineAl-Qahtani The right and the left nodes in your example are at the same depth. The statement from the OP does not say anything about the order of expansion of nodes at the same depth: as far as the BFS algorithm is concerned, the order of sibling expansion could be random.

Comment: You mean that I can exand any node from nodes that have the same depth(sibling )?

Comment: @JasmineAl-Qahtani Not all nodes that have the same depth are siblings, except when depth=1. You need to expand all siblings of a node before moving on to the next node, but the order in which you expand them (i.e. put them in the queue) is not important to BFS.

Answer (score 2):

This means that if you compute the length `L(v)` of the shortest path from starting node to each individual node `v` in your graph, with BFS nodes with lower `L(v)` are always processed before nodes with higher `L(v)`.

Simpler explanation: BFS always starts and processes all nodes that are direct neighbours of starting node. Then it processes all direct neighbours of direct neighbours of starting nodes (excluding the ones already processed) and so on.

The last nodes to be processed are the ones with the longest distance from starting node.

Answer (score 0):

Simply means root node is expanded and then we get their child nodes and then we put the child node in rear end of open queue in BFS.